# How to Find words before and after keyword in python without inbuilt method

Tags: python

I want to find the word before and after the keyword wihtout using inbuilt method

code is working fine with `partition` method

```
mystring =  "This is python class"
keyword = ' is'
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = mystring.partition(keyword)
l = []
l.append(before_keyword)
l.append(keyword)
l.append(after_keyword)
print(l)
```

My output and expected out is below

`['This', ' is', ' python class']`

Sample input for testing
input  >> `"This hello is to test"`

keyword  >> `' is'`

Expected out >> `['This hello', 'is', 'to test']`

Comment: find the position of the word in the list. Then assign all values before the index to before_keyword, and all values after the index + len of search word to after_keyword

Comment: Are you saying you can't use `find` as an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to use in-built methods, you can create your own `partition` or `not_partition` :P

```
inp = "This hello is to test"

def not_partition(inp='', part_at=''):
    inp = inp.strip().split()
    ret = ['']
    for i,v in enumerate(inp):
        if v==part_at:
            ret = ret+[part_at, '']
        else:
            ret[-1] = (ret[-1]+' '+v).strip()
    if ret[-1]=='': del ret[-1]
    return ret

not_partition(inp, 'is'), not_partition(inp, 'test')
```

```
['This hello', 'is', 'to test'], ['This hello is to', 'test']
```

You can also create a more efficient recursive `not_partition` :D

```
def not_partition(inp='', part_at=''):
    inp = inp.strip().split()
    i=0
    while i<len(inp):
        if inp[i]==part_at:
            return [' '.join(inp[:i]), part_at]+not_partition(' '.join(inp[i+1:]),part_at)
        else:
            i+=1
    return [' '.join(inp)] if inp!=[] else []
not_partition(inp, 'is'), not_partition(inp, 'test'), not_partition(inp, 'what?')
```

```
['This hello', 'is', 'to test'],
 ['This hello is to', 'test'],
 ['This hello is to test']
```

Comment: the questioner asked for a solution that doesn't require any "inbuilt method" of python (if I understood correctly). `strip`, `split` etc methods you've used in your solution are "inbuilt methods"...

Comment: Yea. no built in function can be used. So our solution has to be without any of those options.

Comment: Yup! Let me know if you want me to write those as well! `not_strip` and `not_split` :P But then you have to do `not_len` maybe `not_append` ;~) as well, also splitting strings using `:`... It will become a whole new world! If OP asks I will update!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `insert` and `split` as follows:

```
mystring = mystring.split(keyword)
mystring.insert(1, keyword)
print(mystring)
```

Output:

```
['This', ' is', ' python class']
```

---

**Edit:**

To make the code work with every kind of string, you can use this massive code:

```
mystring =  "This is python class and it is a unicorn"
keyword = 'is'
newlist = []
if keyword in mystring:
    string = ''
    for i in mystring.split():
        if i == keyword:
            newlist.append(string)
            newlist.append(i)
            string = ''
        else:
            string += i + ' '
    newlist.append(string)
    newlist = [i.strip() for i in newlist if i]
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'python class and it', 'is', 'a unicorn']
```

Comment: If keyword is not found, it will provide incorrect result. Also, keyword may not be always the 2nd element in the ist

Comment: why line number 10 `string = ''`  is doing

Comment: @Nons I am keep adding the values to the `string` variable, when it sees there is a word that is the same as the `keyword` variable (in this case `is`), it will add the `string` variable as one element to the list, then add the keyword (`is`) then reset the `string` variable to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

## with no functions. just string compare using `==`

If you are not allowed to use any builtin function, then one of the option is to do string compare. I assume you cannot use len() builtin function as well.

```
mystring =  "This is python class and it is a unicorn"
keyword = 'is'
list_of_words = []
word = ''
key_len = str_len = 0
#to get length of keyword as you cannot use len(keyword)
for _ in keyword: key_len +=1
for _ in mystring: str_len +=1
i = 0
start_pos = 0
if keyword in mystring:
    while i < str_len:
        if mystring[i:i+key_len] == keyword:
            if i != 0:
                list_of_words.append(mystring[start_pos:i])
            list_of_words.append(keyword)
            i += key_len
            start_pos = i
        else:
            i+=1
    if start_pos != str_len and start_pos != 0:
        list_of_words.append(mystring[start_pos:])
if list_of_words:
    print (list_of_words)
else:
    print (keyword, 'is not found in', mystring)
```

Output is as follows:

Input words:

```
mystring =  "This is python class and it is a unicorn"
keyword = ' is'
```

Output:

```
['This', ' is', ' python class and it', ' is', ' a unicorn']
```

Input words:

```
mystring =  "This is python class and it is a unicorn"
keyword = ' unicorn'
```

Output:

```
['This is python class and it is a', ' unicorn']
```

Input words:

```
mystring =  "This is python class and it is a unicorn"
keyword = ' as'
```

Output:

```
 as is not found in This is python class and it is a unicorn
```

Input words:

```
mystring =  "This is python class and it is a unicorn"
keyword = 'This'
```

Output:

```
['This', ' is python class and it is a unicorn']
```

## use find function

You can search for the keyword and create the list as follows:

```
mystring =  "This is python class"
keyword = ' as'
l = []
x = mystring.find(keyword)
if x != -1:
    l.append(mystring[:x])
    l.append(keyword)
    l.append(mystring[x+len(keyword):])
    print (l)
else:
    print (keyword, 'is not found in', mystring)
```

Comment: "This is python class and it is a unicorn" not working

Comment: Ah. Checking for the keyword more than once. Hmm. I didnt think about it. Good catch. I am breaking out of the loop as soon as I find the keyword.

Comment: Fixed the multiple occurrences of a keyword. Also checked if word is first or last word in the string.

Comment: if word is first, then previous is ignored. If word is last, then after is ignored. Let me know if you want to print empty string to denote the beginning or after.

Comment: Note that words like `as` and `is` will get split for `class` and `This`. If you want to eliminate that, the code can get more complex. I know this is a python class exercise so working with you on the solution. In real world, you will use a builtin method/function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using regex for this problem

```
import re

keyword = 'is'
str1 = "This hello is to test"
partition = re.split(r'\s({0})\s'.format(keyword), str1)
partition

['This hello', 'is', 'to test']
```

Comment: we all fell for it. We can't use builtin function. This is like therapy. writing code without the use of any of the built in function :)